# Can we share SharePoint 2013 Server between Developers?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We are in the process of developing a new SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted App, i should be preparing any required hardware for team and i need to know if is it neceessary to have a separate SharePoint server for each developer.

All of our machines will have Windows 8, Office 2013 and VS 2013, we will use it to develop the App and we will connect to a SharePoint Server.

Now, can we all connect to the same SharePoint server or do we need to have a separte server for each developer?

NB: the web app for the SP App will be hosted on our machines not on the SP server.

Answer (score 2):

i would create VM on windows 8 machine for each developer. I would never give access to our main SharePoint farm for development purpose. Let the developer develop solutions on their VM then deploy the app into SharePoint farm. you will save alot of troubles.

Comment: Thanks @Waqas Sarwar MCSE
We can't host the VMs on Windows 8 as the machines won't have enough memory and we will have to upgrade which will be costy

We don't have a main SharePoint farm, we create it as per need, and we will have a farm for testing and staging, so this is not a problem

Comment: oh ok, i am not aware you have different set of farms. Your test/dev farm you can share with multiple users. here is very nice article, which will guide you in right direction...http://sharepoint.inproc.com/building-a-sharepoint-development-farm/

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an auto-hosted app I presume, that may not needed to build separate SharePoint VM. Even for SharePoint-hosted App may not need to give separate VM. They can build in their own machine and point it to development server to deploy.

Unless you want to build SharePoint server solutions (wsp), then you would need a separate VM.

Comment: We will be developing a Provider hosted App using MVC as the web application and it will be hosted on the developer machines

I was thinking of sharing a single VM that has SharePoint 2013 installed and i will create a separate Web Application with App Catalog for each developer, this way each developer will use his machine for developent and use the web application on SharePoint VM for deployment

Comment: That should be OK. If they're develop different apps, different web app, different app catalogs, is fine. That's the beauty of SP2013 apps compared to server solutions (wsp) which already there since SP2003.

Comment: We will be working on the same App

Comment: You said will create different web appl and different app catalog. But now you said they will develop the same app. How is that possible? Could you be more spesific? If that will be on the same app, I suggest you use TFS to control other's work.

Comment: I am not sure where i mentiond that we will develop differnt Apps, but anyway, we will be a team working on the same project, so we will be developing the same App, the App will be Proivder Hosted.